# Relative positioning of tikz pic containing multiple nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, tikz-pic, tikz-positioning

I have a tikz pic that contains more than one node, but I am running into a problem when trying to position the pic relative to something else.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[test/.pic = {
  \node [draw, minimum size = 15mm] (big) {} ;
  \node [draw, red] at (big) {\tikzpictext} ;
}]

\pic ["A"] (top-) {test} ;
\node [circle, draw, below = of top-big] (middle) {} ;
\pic ["B", below = of middle] (bottom-) {test} ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Everything is fine except for the positioning of the red `B` node, which is supposed to be centred inside the larger node.  It appears that what's happening is that the option `below = of middle` in the bottom pic is being given to both nodes that make up the pic instead of just the first (`big`) node.  The second node of the pic then gets two conflicting positioning options, namely `below = of middle` and `at (big)`, which apparently causes the weird behaviour.

Is there any way to make the positioning option `below = of middle` apply only to one node of the pic?  Or is there any other way to fix my problem?

Comment: `below=of …` sets `anchor=north`. This applies to both nodes. It does not conflict with `at (big)`, it clarifies it (which anchor `at (big)`?). Do `anchor=center` at the second node if you want its anchor to be `at (big)` (which is also the center of `big`, i.e. `big.center`).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Your solution of putting `anchor=center` does work here, but I'm still confused about what's going on because if I replace pic B with individual nodes like this: `\node [draw, minimum size = 15mm, below = of middle] (bottom) {} ;  \node [draw, red, below = of middle, anchor = center] at (bottom) {B} ;` the result isn't centred.  And also if I flip the order of `below = of middle` and `anchor = center`, I get a different but still wrong result.  So there does seem to be some conflict between the two positioning options, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: `below=of middle` does not only set `anchor=north` but also `at=(middle.south)` and `yshift=-1cm` (that's the default [`node distance`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/node:distance)). But then you set `anchor=center` and `at (bottom)` which finally puts the node's center 1cm below of `bottom`. What are you trying to do in the big picture? Your pic could be written as a node with a label `\node[draw, minimum size=15mm, label={[draw, red]center:A}]{};` without having to deal with this effect.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel That explanation makes sense, thanks.  The only question now is why pic B works properly (after the pic's code is modified to include `anchor = centre`) while it doesn't work when replaced by the two node commands in my previous comment, which (I think) should be equivalent to the pic code.  Your explanation explains well why the formatting is messed up in the scenario with two nodes, but I don't know why it isn't also messed up when using the pic.  Probably some weird peculiarity of how pics get processed or something. ...

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel But anyway, `anchor = centre` solved my original problem so if you want to put that in an answer I will select it as the best answer.